# Exact match on some fields and "fuzzy" search on others?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am attempting to create a query to exactly match on a few fields, such as `account_id` and `from_addresses` (which is an array), while also fuzzy matching on another field such as `message_content`. What is the best way to do this?

I have tried a Bool query with a few `must` and `should` parameters but can't seem to get it working.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: Having a similar problem myself. I have this so far (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528933/elastic-search-fuzzy-match-with-exact-matches-showing-first) but get malformed query errors. Did you ever fix this Taylor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do it to use Filters.  More specifically, an AND filter.  So your query `message_content`, but filter by `account_id` and `from_addresses`.

I don't know which library you are using, so I can't really provide any code examples.